# How do I ignore if value is NULL when matching xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a method where I'm matching to XML files. Both XML's has the same ClientRefNr. But I'm trying to get all information from both and match it to one XML. That works fine. but sometimes, the Doc1 has some IDs that doesn't exist in Doc2 (NULL). And that is what I need to just jump over and continue.

**XML1:**

```
 <Table1>
    <Id>1581016</ClientRefNr>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <Value>All commentary</Value>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ClientRefNr>754030</ClientRefNr>
    <Id>17</Id>
    <Value>All commentary</Value>
  </Table1>
```

**XML2:**

```
 <Table1>
    <ClientRefNr>1581016</ClientRefNr>
    <Id>12</Id>
    <Name>All commentary</Name>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <ClientRefNr>75885</ClientRefNr>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Name>Martin</Name>
  </Table1>
```

**What I tried with C#**

```
    public XDocument MatchClientCommWithLZ(XDocument ClientCommXML, XDocument doc2)
    {
        XDocument result = new XDocument();
        List<XElement> doc1Elements = ClientCommXML.Root.Elements().ToList();
        List<XElement> doc2Elements = doc2.Root.Elements().ToList();


        XElement accountElement = new XElement("ClientRefNr");
        result = new XDocument(accountElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < doc1Elements.Count(); i++)
        {
            XmlDocument subDoc = new XmlDocument();
            subDoc.LoadXml(doc1Elements[i].ToString());

            string tableName = subDoc.FirstChild.Name;
            string ClientRefNr = doc1Elements[i].Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "ClientRefNr").FirstOrDefault().Value;



            List<XElement> doc1Childs = doc1Elements[i].Elements().ToList();
            List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault().Elements().ToList();

            XElement tblElement = new XElement(tableName);
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("Id", GetClientValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "Id")));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("ClientRefNr", GetClientValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "ClientRefNr")));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("Name", GetClientValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "Name")));
            tblElement.Add(new XElement("Value", GetClientValue(doc1Childs, doc2Childs, "Value")));



            accountElement.Add(tblElement);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

And that works very fine. But When I hit a `ClientRefNr` where the value does not exist in `Doc2` I get this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' because this is NULL

List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault().Elements().ToList();
```

Any ideas, how to ignorer if ClientRefNr doesn't exist in Doc2

Comment: This is because you are using [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1), which returns null if no item was found. Then you are directly calling `.Elements()` on what could potentially be `null`. You can either split it up, so you call `FirstOrDefault`, assign that result to a variable, and then check if it's null or not. Or, if nothing else cares if it's null, use the null-conditional operator

Comment: No problem, I'm currently typing an answer that goes into further detail explaining both solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking if the Where function returned any elements?
Change:

```
List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault().Elements().ToList();
```

To:

```
var tempResult = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault();
if(tempResult==null || tempResult.Elements() == null) 
   continue;

//... rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if your C#-Version is high enough (i.e. not building for a very old .NET-Version), would be to use the `?.`-operator, which executes the function when the left side is not null and returns `null` itself if the left side is `null`:
`doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault()?.Elements()?.ToList();`

Then `doc2Childs` will be `null` when the `FirstOrDefault` returned `null`.

If you want it to be an empty list when that happens, you can do 
`doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault()?.Elements()?.ToList() ?? new List<XElement>();`

This causes a new list to be created when the left side is `null`

To summarize:  `a ?? b` is short for `a == null ? b : a` while `a?.b` is short for `a == null ? null : a.b`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to your problem, depending on what you want to do if you encounter a null value in one of your XML files

1. Ignore it and move on
2. Acknowledge it and

   - Move on
   - Skip
   - Break

---

1:

```cs
List<XElement> doc2Childs = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault()?.Elements()?.ToList();
```

Looks like the same thing you had right? Well there's a minute difference, I used the [null-conditional member access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), which:

> applies a member access, ?., or element access, ?[], operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns null

This means your `List<XElement> doc2Childs` may, or may not, be null after this operation, so watch out for further errors down the line

---

2:

```cs
var doc2TempResult = doc2Elements.Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf(ClientRefNr) > -1).FirstOrDefault();

// Instead of continue, you could also break, or do whatever you want/ need
if (doc2TempResult is null || !(doc2TempResult.Elements() is IEnumerable<XElement> doc2Elements))
    continue;

var doc2Childs = doc2Elements.ToList()
```

This one explicitly checks for null, it also checks if the elements of `doc2TempResult` are an `IEnumerable<XElement>` (as specified by the `Elements()` method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Elements)) or not. If they are not, it does the same as if the temp result was null (you can split this into 2 if checks if you want to handle those cases differently). It then turns that IEnumerable into a List by calling `ToList()` as you've done before